# Rails 3: Should I explicitly save an object in an after_create callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

Relevant Code: http://pastebin.com/EnLJUJ8G

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :check_room_schedule

  ...

  scope :for_date, lambda { |date| where(day: date) }
  scope :for_room, lambda { |room| where(room: room) }

  scope :room_stats, lambda { |room| where(room: room) }
  scope :gear_stats, lambda { |gear| where(gear: gear) } 

  def check_room_schedule
    @tasks = Task.for_date(self.day).for_room(self.room).list_in_asc_order
    @self_position = @tasks.index(self)

    if @tasks.length <= 2
      if @self_position == 0 
        self.notes = "There is another meeting in 
    this room beginning at # {@tasks[1].begin.strftime("%I:%M%P")}."
        self.save
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def self.list_in_asc_order
      order('begin asc')
    end
end
```

I'm making a small task app. Each task is assigned to a room. Once I add a task, I want to use a callback to check to see if there are tasks in the same room before and or after the task I just added (although my code only handles one edge case right now).

So I decided to use after_create (since the user will manually check for this if they edit it, hence not after_save) so I could use two scopes and a class method to query the tasks on the day, in the room, and order them by time. I then find the object in the array and start using if statements.

I have to explicitly save the object. It works. But it feels weird that I'm doing that. I'm not too experienced (first app), so I'm not sure if this is frowned upon or if it is convention. I've searched a bunch and looked through a reference book, but I haven't see anything this specific.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a task for `before_create` to me. If you have to save in your `after_*` callback, you probably meant to use a `before_*` callback instead.

In `before_create` you wouldn't have to call `save`, as the save happens after the callback code runs for you.

And rather than saving then querying to see if you get 2 or more objects returns, you should be querying for one object that will clash before you save.

In psuedo code, what you have now:

```
after creation
  now that I'm saved, find all tasks in my room and at my time
  did I find more than one?
    Am I the first one?
      yes: add note about another task, then save again
      no: everything is fine, no need to re-save any edits
```

What you should have:

```
before creation
  is there at least 1 task in this room at the same time?
    yes: add note about another task
    no: everything is fine, allow saving without modification
```

Something more like this:

```
before_create :check_room_schedule
def check_room_schedule
  conflicting_task = Task.for_date(self.day)
                         .for_room(self.room)
                         .where(begin: self.begin) # unsure what logic you need here...
                         .first
  if conflicting_task
    self.notes =
      "There is another meeting in this room beginning at #{conflicting_task.begin.strftime("%I:%M%P")}."
  end
end
```

Comment: Since the scopes wouldn't load this object (or am I wrong about this?), I would need to insert this object into the @tasks array manually, correct?

Comment: See my edit. Basically check for 1 conflict before you save, rather than seeing if your query returns 2 or more objects after the save.

Comment: Checking for a record in the database the ActiveRecord finder method `exists?` should be used. See [Active Record API Dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F)

Comment: Alex, thank you. That's an interesting approach and seems like a much cleaner way to go. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @unnu You could use that, and it would be a little faster. But the original code uses a field on the existing task in the note on the newly created task. So you would need to actually fetch the record in order to achieve that.